# log4j2 runtime configuration - in clustered/docker environment

Tags: docker, log4j2

I have various loggers with different log levels.

Initially loaded from a log4j2.xml

`<Logger name="a.b.c" level="INFO">`

I want to provide an option to modify or update the log levels at runtime using an API. The following lines of code work fine. I am just mentioning the relevant lines.

```
LoggerContext cxt = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
for (Logger l : cxt.getLoggers()) {
     ....
     // I am getting logger config of the logger (I am doing this update only once per unique logger config)
     LoggerConfig lc = l.get();
     // This won't be hardcoded but will be obtained from request
     lc.setLevel(Level.ERROR);
}
cxt.updateLoggers();
```

As mentioned this works fine when I test the application locally. It is updating all the loggers.

I was going through log4j2 configuration update documentation
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/cloud.html

> **Managing Logging Configuration**
>
> Also, in a micro-services, clustered environment it is quite likely that these changes will need to be propagated to multiple servers at the same time. Trying to achieve this via REST calls could be difficult.

I am just wondering how can this propagation be achieved in a clustered environment or with multiple docker containers of the application running. I know I can call the update on individual containers but my question is about any possibility to update log levels in all containers programmatically in one go?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reviewing [Logging in the Cloud](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/cloud.html) and taking a look at the [Log4j Spring Cloud Sample Application](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/tree/release-2.x/log4j-spring-cloud-config/log4j-spring-cloud-config-samples/log4j-spring-cloud-config-sample-application). If you are using a Spring Boot application it can automatically be notified when changes are made to the logging configuration hosted in Spring Cloud Config. Multiple applications can share a single configuration file.

You can accomplish the same thing without Spring Boot but it will be more difficult as you would have to implement your own RabbitMQ event listener and trigger Log4j's Watcher.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it out differently. I am not accepting it as answer but your comments make sense.